# How to deal with data from arff file with python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, arff

I am pretty new for python. I am using python to read the arff file now:

```
import arff

for row in arff.load('cpu.arff'):   
    x = row
    print(x)
```

The part of sample output is like this format:

```
<Row(125.0,256.0,6000.0,256.0,16.0,128.0,198.0)>
<Row(29.0,8000.0,32000.0,32.0,8.0,32.0,269.0)>
<Row(29.0,8000.0,32000.0,32.0,8.0,32.0,220.0)>
<Row(29.0,8000.0,32000.0,32.0,8.0,32.0,172.0)>
<Row(29.0,8000.0,16000.0,32.0,8.0,16.0,132.0)>
<Row(26.0,8000.0,32000.0,64.0,8.0,32.0,318.0)>
<Row(23.0,16000.0,32000.0,64.0,16.0,32.0,367.0)>
```

Actually, only the last column of data is the label, and the rest of data are the attributes. I am wondering how I can save them by using array? 
Because I want to assign the data of last column as y, and the first six column data as my x, and then I will do the cross-validation for the data from arff file.

Or is there any approaches to separate data by attributes and label from arff file automatically?

Comment: If `row` is an array, then you can use `x = row[:-1]` and `y = row[6]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row objects from `arff` module [support typical python array slicing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/arff/0.9), thus you can separate data from labels easily

```
import arff

X = []
y = []

for row in arff.load('cpu.arff'):   
    X.append(row[:-1])
    y.append(row[-1])
```

Comment: I'm trying like u said, but i'm getting "TypeError: unhashable type". Any ideia? Ty :)

Comment: show the exact code, the above one does not need hashing, maybe you use set/dictionary instead of lists?