# How to edit data in .arff file?

Tags: apache-spark, arff

I am trying to run a 5 GB sized .arff file on Apache Spark, and I want to edit some data within this file. How can I edit an .arff file?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the `arff` package to open it:

```
import arff

X = []
y = []

for row in arff.load('cpu.arff'):   
    X.append(row[:-1])
    y.append(row[-1])
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600053/how-to-deal-with-data-from-arff-file-with-python) is a similar question.